# Hello, world without main method (by Horstmann)

Tags: java

Horstmann in Core Java 7th edition writes that it is possible to show Hello, world without main method. It is done like this:

```java
public class Hello{
    static{
        System.out.println("Hello, world");
    }
}
```

He says that first of all Hello, world will be written. And only then you will receive an error message.

I use

```
java version "1.7.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode)
```

And I fail to model this. Has it already been fixed?

Comment: javac Hello.java then java Hello

Comment: and what is the error you are getting

Comment: Error: Main method not found in class Hello, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)

Comment: run this code getting error is  
Error: Class names 'Hello', are accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested.  
what this error means ?  
using java 8

Comment: @assylias No it is not a duplicate. There is behavior change between java 7 and prior versions. The user is reading a book of a previous version but running the code on java 7.

Comment: @JunedAhsan Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Java 7** looks for a main method before loading the class. This is a behavior change from previous java versions and hence your `static` block is not executing. In previous versions, the behavior was that JRE used to look for main method post loading the class and after executing the static blocks.

So if you run your code on any version prior to java 7 you will see that `static` block executes.

The book you are reading may not be written for java 7 but the jdk& jre you are using to execute the samples is version 7.

**An advice** : As a good reading practice you should try to run the book samples on the same version as specified in the book to avoid confusion. Although in this instance, your confusion lead you to learn something new about java 7.

Answer (score 2):

Prior to Java 7 JVM used to load the class before searching for the main() method.

```
public class Hello{
    static{
        System.out.println("Hello, world");
    }
}
```

So when you execute this by `java Hello` class will be loaded first and `Hello, world` will be printed(static methods/block are executed when classes are loaded and classes are loaded when they are referenced). Then JVM will search for main() method in Hello class and will throw an error as it is not present. However this is fixed in java 7. So if you are using java 7 then you will directly get an error.